# Trying to Message User which option was selected from content control dropdown list

Tags: vba, ms-word

So basically I have a content control dropdown list called "Letterhead", and I'm trying to make it so when the user exits letterhead the name of the quick part selected is displayed.  My code right now (below) displays the name "Letterhead" rather than say "Mesa" which is the name of the letterhead inserted.

```
MsgBox "The user selected a file, specifically: " & ContentControl.Tag
```

And here is the result

[image]

The content control contains images for 4 cities, and each one is a quick part with a name, i.e. "Toronto" or "Mesa".  These Names are within the Letterhead category, and the AutoText Gallery, so the dropdown menu allows users to select one of the images from the letterhead category, I am just trying to figure out the code that would state the name of the image (i.e. Mesa for the Mesa letterhead)

Comment: `ContentControl.Range.Text` will return what's displayed in the content control dropdown...

Comment: Hi @CindyMeister if I do that, nothing is displayed, because the options in the drop down are images, that are named after cities, so there is no actual text to display.  I need to display the "name" of that image, I.e. this is the letterhead image named Cambridge

Comment: Use the [edit] link to provide this important information *in your question*. How do you expect anyone to know that? Also describe how you managed to load an image to a dropdown content control. And how is this "name" stored in the content control?

Comment: @CindyMeister ok I have done that, thanks

Comment: I don't think it's possible. As best I can tell, the content control keeps no record of which entry was selected. I've looked in the underlying Word Open XML and there's nothing there, only the content that was inserted. I found three other queries on the Internet for this and they all received no answers. The only method that occurs to me would be non-trivial: breaking the picture down to base64 and comparing it to all the BuildingBlocks stored in the template you're taking them from until it finds a match, then extracting the "name" information.

Comment: A simpler approach could be to recreate these Building Block. Assign the value you want to the "Alternative Text" (AltText) of the graphic before making it into a Building Block. Then you can read that property from the graphic in the content control.

Comment: @cindymeister thank you! I will give this a try